# python script for printing two consecutive word with the text in another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python and I need to create a script in which I have two files :
first file contains only locations in the format given below:

```
1 London
2 United Kingdom
3 Rome
4 USA
5 Italy
6 Texas
```

and in the second file I have text given below:

```
MATCH p=AllShortestPaths((c:City {name:"%a"})-[*]->(c:City {name:"%b"}))  
return p;
```

So at the moment, I want to create an output file, in which it should copy the text from the second file and substitute first location and second location from first file instead of $a and %b in the text.

and it should keep on doing in this matter like first loop should retrieve `location 1` and `location 2` then next `location 1` and `location 3` then so on. once list is finished then start with `location 2` and `location 3` then `location 2` and `location 4` and so on until all words are retrieved.

Comment: Any reason to not amend the cypher query to match all City nodes where the names are in the list, then find the path where the names aren't equal?

Comment: actually I have neo4j database for whole world and it would take lot of time to find the distance between each and every location. and also second problem is that, this list is just an example. I have around 700 files filled with lists.

Comment: I'm not saying all nodes... Reduce the match to the six, then use where a.name <> b.name on the subsequent match...?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? SO is not a free code writing service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty complex, but i think this two things should help you:

### Combinations Iterable

Use itertools.combinations to get iterable of all pairs:

***Code:***

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations([1,2,3],2))
```

***Output:***

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

### Replace

***Code:***

```
"spam Spanish cheese Spanish".replace("Spanish","inquisition")
```

***Output:***

```
"spam inquisition cheese inquisition"
```

So proposed code would look like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

with open("first_file") as f:
    cities = (city.strip() for city in f.readlines())

with open("second_file") as f:
    cypher_query = f.readlines()

with open("third_file","w") as f:
    for city1,city2 in combinations(cities,2):
        f.writelines(line.replace("%a",city1).replace("%b",city2) for line in cypher_query)
        f.write("\n")
```